# CodeIgniter - retrieving all posts except the last from table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My scenario:

- I want to post all threads from a table in my DB, except for the very last one. I've tried to use `select_max`, but it doesn't work. I can't seem to figure out what to put in my query string.

I just want to retrieve all posts and offset it by 1.

Comment: How about showing a schema? My *guess* would be you just do a for loop (with asc order) and a count - 1 (omiting the last post) but then again why not just 'know' the last id and grab all but that id?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100,1` (limit 100, offset by 1)

or you get all the posts and in when looping through them in codeigniter you could do something like this:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($posts as $p):
    if($i != 1):
        //show posts
    endif;
$i++;
endforeach;
```

Comment: "(limit 100, offset by 1)" is `LIMIT 1, 100`

Comment: Thanx guys - But One Question...
I dont want to know the total amount of my table count...
Can I take The total count, and put it in a variable - and them tell it to LIMIT by 1... 
And in that case - what to do ???

Thanx Again - from a frustrating Dude.....

Comment: @MyungKi You could maybe place in a really high number that you know you wouldn't get to like 99999 as a quick solution